# Was the Jubilee in mind in Isaiah 49:8-9 and 61:1-2?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, isaiah-yeshaya-the-book, yovel

Did the prophet Isaiah have the Jubilee in mind in [Isaiah 49:8](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1049.htm#8) and [61:1-2](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1061.htm#1)?  I notice the term "proclaim freedom" appears in Leviticus as well as Isaiah 61. Is the similarity superficial?

In the case of Isaiah 49:8 it alludes to a "time of favor," but admittedly is not explicit. However, I hope at least to get an opinion on the chapter 61 reference.